# Opera problem with javascript on submit

Tags: javascript, submit, opera

I have an input element with onchange="do_something()". When I am typing and hit the enter key it executes correctly (do_something first, submit then) on Firefox and Chromium (not tested in IE and Safari), however in Opera it doesn't (it submits immediately). I tried using a delay like this:

```
<form action="." method="POST" onsubmit="wait_using_a_big_loop()">
<input type="text" onchange="do_something()">
</form>
```

but it didn't work either.

Do you have some recommendations?

Edit:
Finally I used a mix of the solutions provided by iftrue and crescentfresh, just unfocus the field to fire do_something() method, I did this because some other input fields had others methods onchange.

```
$('#myForm').submit( function(){
    $('#id_submit').focus();
} );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jquery and hijack the form.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit

```
<form id = "myForm">

</form>

   $('#myForm').submit( function(){
   do_something();
   } );
```

This should submit the form after calling that method. If you need more fine-grained control, throw a return false at the end of the submit event and make your own post request with $.post();

Answer (score 2):

From http://cross-browser.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=123:

> Per the spec, pressing enter is not
>   supposed to fire the change event. The
>   change event occurs when a control
>   loses focus and its value has changed.
>
> In IE pressing enter focuses the
>   submit button - so the text input
>   loses focus and this causes a change
>   event.
>
> In FF pressing enter does not focus
>   the submit button, yet the change
>   event still occurs.
>
> In Opera neither of the above occurs.

`keydown` is more consistent across browsers for detecting changes in a field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great at Javascript, but could you do something like this?

```
<form name="myform" action="." method="POST">
<input type="text" onchange="do_something();document.myform.submit();">
</form>
```